# Regex to match digits and at most one space between them

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match phone numbers in the following patterns:

```
9 99 99 99 99
0999999999
11 0999999999
9 9999 9999
```

But not the following:

```
9 99  99 99 99 (two spaces)
9 99\n99 99 99
```

Therefore, I want to match 7 to 12 digits and an optional spaces between them, but not sequences of more than one white space.

So far I came up with `"[\d ?]{7,12}"`, but it doesn't really match the requirements as the spaces are counted in the {7,12} and it also matches two sequences of spaces.

Comment: Try [`\b\d(?: ?\d){6,9}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/uk1VVx/1/)

Comment: I think that's it, thanks! I edited the question because I actually meant 12, not 10 but the idea is the same

Comment: So you want to match spaces (the space character) but not arbitrary whitespace (space, tab, newline, etc.)? You may want to remove the word white from your title and question in that case. It's misleading.

Comment: Done. I guess I didn't know the real meaning of "white space"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[\d ?]{7,12}` is a pattern that matches 7 to 12 digit, space or `?` chars. It can match a `???????` string because `?` is not a quantifier, but a mere question mark symbol when declared inside a character class.

If you change it to `(?:\d ?){7,12}`, you may partially solve the problem, the space at the end. I suggest using

```
\b\d(?: ?\d){6,11}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uk1VVx/2)

The word boundaries `\b` will make sure you only match whole words.

**Details**

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `\d` - a digit
- `(?: ?\d){6,11}` - 6 to 11 consecutive sequences of

  - `?` - an optional space
  - `\d` - a single digit
- `\b` - trailing word boundary.

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
\d(\s?\d){6,11}
```

the first `\d` matches on the first digit.  Next can follow a group of 6 to 11 (to make a total of 7 to 12) pairs of an optional space, followed by a digit.  Multiple spaces are not allowed, as you see each optional space has digits to both sides.  It can be checked [here](https://regex101.com/r/Yuss2N/1)  That regexp is equivalent, but shorter, to this one:

```
\d\s?\d\s?\d\s?\d\s?\d\s?\d((((((\s?\d)?\s?\d)?\s?\d)?\s?\d)?\s?\d)?\s?\d)?
```

that can be checked [here](https://regex101.com/r/Yuss2N/2).

## NOTE

See that the `\s` matches a newline, so you can get multiline number (as shown in the examples)  If you don't like that behaviour, then narrow the space class using a simple space, as in

```
\d( ?\d){6,11}
```

that can be tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/Yuss2N/3)  Look, that now, a more than 12 digits number is truncated to only the first twelve, if this is not desired, use word boundary at the end, as in

```
\d( ?\d){6,11}\b
```

See it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Yuss2N/4).

Answer (score 2):

I'd try

```
(?:\d+ ?){7,12}
```

The original regex was matching a character group of a space OR a digit seven to twelve times. The supplied regex matches a digit followed by a possible space seven to twelve times. That way the spaces aren't counted as part of the total.